# How to show $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent of each other?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

If I have a random variable $X$, and a Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, what would I need to show in order to prove $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent?

I know that for some Borel sets $B_1$ and $B_2$, proving $P(X\in B_1, f(X)\in B_2)=P(X\in B_1)P(f(X)\in B_2)$ would show independence. However, clearly $X$ and $f(X)$ can't be independent...unless $X$ is independent of itself, right? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Correct, since $f(x) = x$ is an example of a function satisfying your conditions, therefore according to  your statement $X$ must be independent to itself, which means that $X$ must be..

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to prove that X is independent of itself solely based on the information I have? I'm told to prove the condition, but I'm not sure whether I actually have to show the condition holds or just that it is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @Jax You cannot prove that $X$ is independent of itself. If that is what you are asked to prove then the question is wrong. I have added a counter-example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent implies $f(X)$ is independent of itself, and that $f(X)$ is independent of itself iff $f(X)$ is almost surely constant.

From this you cannot conclude that $X$ is almost surely constant if no further information about $f$ is given.

Example: let $X$ take values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $\frac 1 2 $ each and $f(x)=x^{2}$. Then $f(X)=1$ and this makes $X$ and $f(X)$ independent. But $X$ is not a constant.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing I know is that is f is Borel measurable, so I guess the requirement would be that X is a constant with probability 1. Thanks!

Comment: The first "iff" should read "implies", which suffices to conclude.

Comment: @Did Actually, if $f(X)$ is independent of itself then $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent (because it $f(X)$ is a constant), so there was no mistake in my statements. Perhaps, it is easier to understand my answer if I have just 'implies' there, so I have edited my answer.

Comment: **In the end**, all properties 1, 2 and 3 are equivalent, but the way you write it, one is led to believe that 1 being equivalent to 2 is obvious while actually, they are because of 3.